# TinyMCE write to database and retrieve from database

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor that sends it's data to my database. The code that makes it work (so SQL doesn't throw a syntax error):

```
$artikel = htmlentities($_POST["artikel"]);
```

But now i'm trying to put it back into a TinyMCE editor to change the text. This kinda works but the formating isn't coppied over (see image).
The code for this is:

```
echo'<script>$( window ).load(function(){tinymce.get("artikel").setContent("' . $row["Tekst"] . '");});</script>';
```

[image]

How can i make it so the text gets put in the editor with the formatting applied?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got formatted text because HTML tags was escaped. For example

should be transformed to &lt;p&gt;. Please check what exactly are you getting in $row["Tekst"].

To reverse this behavior you can use

```
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

Remember, this is unsafe for security!

Comment: Oke that seems to work thanks!
But why is this unsafe?

Comment: You can get nasty things in $row['Tekst'] like HTML div which will hide your page or javascript code.

Comment: Oke so wierdly at the end of the text there is still `&lt;/p&gt;` after escaping. All the rest seems to be fine.